# How to set default HTTP headers on client side and access them in server methods with Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

In a Meteor app, I have a few methods like this one :

```
Meteor.methods({
   'foo': async function (...args) {
     const forwardedFor = this.connection.httpHeaders['x-forwarded-for'] ||
                          this.connection.clientAddress,
     // ...
   },
   ...
});
```

I would like to be able to send some information from the client side to these methods without relying on method arguments, for example a browser [fingerprint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs), but [Session](https://docs.meteor.com/api/session.html) is not available on the server so I have to resolve to use custom HTTP headers.

But how can I tell Meteor to send some custom HTTP headers with each method calls?

### Edit

To be clear, this is what I'm trying to do :

#### 1. Application starts

```
// headers['x-some-value'] = 'foo';
Meteor.startup(async () => {
  // or
  // headers['x-some-value'] = 'foo';
});
```

#### 2. Client calls a method

```
Meteor.call('superMethod', data, (error, result) => { ... });
```

#### 3. Server handles method call

```
Meteror.methods({
  'superMethod': async function (data) {
     const someValue this.connection.httpHeaders['x-some-value'] );
     // -> 'foo'
     ...
  }
});
```

Comment: I misread your question two times, so just to be clear: you want to add custom headers at the client (during Meteor.call) so you can read them server-side using `this.connection`?

Comment: As Jan pointed out in his first answer, method calls don't use HTTP then are sent over the websocket connection. So no, this isn't currently possible. But you can easily use Picker or one of the REST packages to setup server-side routes to go old-school and set up HTTP end-points for your app which you can then call from the client with whatever headers you want. You won't be able to validate the current user in those API endpoints though.

Comment: @Jankapunkt I am aware that Meteor uses WebSockets whenever possible (it does default to HTTP if the client has no support for it), but I do not need to have dynamic HTTP headers; if I can only add some headers when the app is starting up, that's fine. The point is to **not** have to pass a certain value every time the client calls a method, but have this value passed through the HTTP headers. So: 1) app starts and sets some HTTP headers, 2) client executes `Metehor.call`, 3) server reads the HTTP headers in the method associated with that client.